# Different ways of clearing lists

Tags: python, list

Is there any reason to do anything more complicated than one of these two lines when you want to clear a list in Python?

```
old_list = []
old_list = list()
```

The reason I ask is that I just saw this in some running code:

```
del old_list[ 0:len(old_list) ]
```

Comment: Why are you doing this?  Garbage Collection works.  Why not simply ignore the old list value and let Python clean it up automatically?

Comment: @S.Lott: The poster didn't write the code, and is asking why the original writer may have done so.

Comment: You could also do: while l: l.pop()

Comment: LOL. I'm sure that's efficient.

Comment: Nobody said anything asbout it being efficient...

Comment: Not related to your question, but you shouldn't use len when specifying a slice. `a[:x]` means beginning to x and `a[x:]` means x to end. `a[ 0:len(a) ]` can be written as `a[:]`. You can also use negatives to count from the end (`a[-1]` is the last element).

Answer (score 385, accepted):

Clearing a list in place will affect all other references of the same list.

For example, this method doesn't affect other references:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = a
>>> a = []
>>> print(a)
[]
>>> print(b)
[1, 2, 3]
```

But this one does:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = a
>>> del a[:]      # equivalent to   del a[0:len(a)]
>>> print(a)
[]
>>> print(b)
[]
>>> a is b
True
```

You could also do:

```
>>> a[:] = []
```

Comment: You could also do `del a[:]`

Comment: Why the first one will only affect `a`? I thought `a` and `b` reference to the same object... Just wanna know why. Thanks.

Comment: With **python 3.3** and later you can go with `a.clear()`, no problem!

Comment: @Stallman because in first you are changing a reference for 'a' to point to new array, not clearing one, and b still points an old one

Comment: It'd be great if anyone can show the performance difference between those methods!

Answer (score 76):

Doing `alist = []` does not clear the list, just creates an empty list and binds it to the variable `alist`. The old list will still exist if it had other variable bindings.

To actually clear a list *in-place*, you can use any of these ways:

1. `alist.clear()  # Python 3.3+, most obvious`
2. `del alist[:]`
3. `alist[:] = []`
4. `alist *= 0     # fastest`

See the [Mutable Sequence Types](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-mutable) documentation page for more details.

Comment: I have tested and alist *= 0  is the fastest, next fastest is alist.clear() and other two methods are equally fast. Could  you explain why alist*= 0 is the fastest?

Comment: @Jenny: It simply uses fewer (or less expensive) [opcodes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) under the hood. For example, the operator version doesn't need to look up any method names or build slices.

Comment: "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it." Python is shining here :)

Comment: Nik, you got my upvote for citing the Zen, but I do not see too many ways to "do it" here… First of all, 4 is certainly not "obvious". And 3 is not doing exactly the same as the other options – it first creates an empty list, from which it then replaces the contents of `alist`. The RHS could also be a populated list, so this option is more powerful, but also slightly more expensive. Finally, I prefer the readability of 1 over 2 and agree with the "most obvious" comment, because "Readability counts", and "Beautiful is better than ugly" anyhow. ;-)

Answer (score 38):

There is a very simple way to clear a python list. Use `del list_name[:]`.

For example:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = a
>>> del a[:]
>>> print a, b
[] []
```

Answer (score 13):

<del>It appears to me that del will give you the memory back, while assigning a new list will make the old one be deleted only when the gc runs.matter.</del>

This may be useful for large lists, but for small list it should be negligible.

**Edit**: As  Algorias, it doesn't  matter.

Note that

```
del old_list[ 0:len(old_list) ]
```

is equivalent to

```
del old_list[:]
```

Comment: gc is not run in cycles. The list is freed as soon as its last reference is dropped.

Comment: Algorias: that's true for CPython, but may not be for other implementations.

Comment: del old_list[ 0:len(old_list) ] and del old_list[:] have a same result, but the latter one is faster (checked in Python 2.6)

Answer (score 9):

```
del list[:]
```

Will delete the values of that list variable

```
del list
```

Will delete the variable itself from memory

Answer (score 5):

There are two cases in which you might want to clear a list:

1. You want to use the name `old_list` further in your code;
2. You want the old list to be garbage collected as soon as possible to free some memory;

In case 1 you just go on with the assigment:

```
    old_list = []    # or whatever you want it to be equal to
```

In case 2 the `del` statement would reduce the reference count to the list object the name `old list` points at. If the list object is only pointed by the name `old_list` at, the reference count would be 0, and the object would be freed for garbage collection.

```
    del old_list
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're clearing the list, you, obviously, don't need the list anymore. If so, you can just delete the entire list by simple del method.

```
a = [1, 3, 5, 6]
del a # This will entirely delete a(the list).
```

But in case, you need it again, you can reinitialize it. Or just simply clear its elements by

```
del a[:]
```

Answer (score -3):

another solution that works fine is to create empty list as a reference empty list.

```
empt_list = []
```

for example you have a list as   `a_list = [1,2,3]`. To clear it just make the following:

```
a_list = list(empt_list)
```

this will make `a_list` an empty list just like the `empt_list`.

Comment: No reason to create empt_list.  Just use a_list = list().