# Different ways of deleting lists

Tags: python, list, memory-management

I want to understand why:

- `a = []`;
- `del a`; and
- `del a[:]`;

behave so differently.

I ran a test for each to illustrate the differences I witnessed:

```
>>> # Test 1: Reset with a = []
... 
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = a
>>> a = []
>>> a
[]
>>> b
[1, 2, 3]
>>> 
>>> # Test 2: Reset with del a
... 
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = a
>>> del a
>>> a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
>>> b
[1, 2, 3]
>>> 
>>> # Test 3: Reset with del a[:]
... 
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = a
>>> del a[:]
>>> a
[]
>>> b
[]
```

I did find [Different ways of clearing lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850795/clearing-python-lists), but I didn't find an explanation for the differences in behaviour. Can anyone clarify this?

Comment: There's also a fourth way, `a[:] = ()`, which does sort of the same as `del a[:]`. Only instead of asking to delete the whole contents of `a`, it asks to replace the whole contents of `a` with the contents of a empty tuple.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Test 1

```
>>> a = [1,2,3] # set a to point to a list [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = a # set b to what a is currently pointing at
>>> a = [] # now you set a to point to an empty list

# Step 1: A --> [1 2 3]

# Step 2: A --> [1 2 3] <-- B

# Step 3: A --> [     ] [1 2 3] <-- B

# at this point a points to a new empty list
# whereas b points to the original list of a
```

### Test 2

```
>>> a = [1,2,3] # set a to point to a list [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = a # set b to what a is currently pointing at
>>> del a # delete the reference from a to the list

# Step 1: A --> [1 2 3]

# Step 2: A --> [1 2 3] <-- B

# Step 3:       [1 2 3] <-- B

# so a no longer exists because the reference
# was destroyed but b is not affected because
# b still points to the original list
```

### Test 3

```
>>> a = [1,2,3] # set a to point to a list [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = a # set b to what a is currently pointing at
>>> del a[:] # delete the contents of the original

# Step 1: A --> [1 2 3]

# Step 2: A --> [1 2 3] <-- B

# Step 2: A --> [     ] <-- B

# both a and b are empty because they were pointing 
# to the same list whose elements were just removed
```

Answer (score 15):

Of your three *"ways of deleting Python lists"*, **only one** actually alters the original list object; the other two only affect *the name*.

1. `a = []` creates a *new list object*, and assigns it to the name `a`.
2. `del a` deletes *the name*, **not** the object it refers to.
3. `del a[:]` deletes *all references* from the list referenced by the name `a` (although, similarly, it doesn't directly affect the objects that were referenced from the list).

It's probably worth reading [this article](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) on Python names and values to better understand what's going on here.

Comment: In point 2 , the list `[1,2,3,4]` still exists in memory or is sent to GC?

Comment: @letsc it depends on whether there are any *other* references to it; `del a` will just remove the name and decrement the reference count of whatever it was pointing to.

Comment: Yep, that sort of what I was trying to say by *so a no longer exists because the reference was destroyed but b is not affected because b still points to the original list*. I don't know if that was very clear.

Comment: ..so it still exists in memory even if dint do a `a=b` before `del a` ? Isnt that very inefficient especially if I delete a list of size say `10**10`

Comment: Hardcoded values always have a location in memory. Try `id(1 - 1)` and `id(0)`. They will have the same id.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi what do you mean *"hardcoded values"*? Literals? Small integers are *interned* in CPython, you should **not** draw conclusions based on their behaviour alone.

Comment: Yes, literals. That's what I mean.

Comment: @letsc if `a` was the *only remaining reference* to the list (i.e. we didn't assign `b = a` or anything similar), then the reference count of the list object will drop to zero and it will be eligible for removal. It isn't necessarily removed immediately, though. Just leaving it in place isn't *inefficient* (it's already there, so it costs nothing) - moving it before we actually needed the space would be, though!

Comment: For sure the most accurate answer. +1

Comment: @jonrsharpe Just check out the article, and I'm glad you linked it. It's the only way to understand references, I tried making diagrams too.

Comment: Under CPython, most types actually *will* be collected immediately when the refcount hits zero, though some built-in types might have free lists, interning, etc. to complicate matters.  Anything forming a reference cycle is also a crapshoot since you have to wait for the garbage collector.

Answer (score 7):

`Test 1:` rebinds `a` to a new object, `b` still holds a *reference* to the original object, `a` is just a name by rebinding `a` to a new object does not change the original object that `b` points to.

`Test 2:` you del the name `a` so it no longer exists but again you still have a reference to the object in memory with `b`.

`Test 3` `a[:]` just like when you copy a list or want to change all the elements of a list refers to references to the objects stored in the list not the name `a`. `b` gets cleared also as again it is a reference to `a` so changes to the content of `a` will effect `b`.

The behaviour is [documented](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#the-del-statement):

> There is a way to remove an item from a list given its index instead
>   of its value: the `del` statement. This differs from the `pop()`
>   method which returns a value. The `del` statement can also be used to
>   remove slices from a list or clear the entire list (which we did
>   earlier by assignment of an empty list to the slice). For example:
>
> ```
> >>>
> >>> a = [-1, 1, 66.25, 333, 333, 1234.5]
> >>> del a[0]
> >>> a
> [1, 66.25, 333, 333, 1234.5]
> >>> del a[2:4]
> >>> a
> [1, 66.25, 1234.5]
> >>> del a[:]
> >>> a
> []
> ```
>
> `del` can also be used to delete entire variables:
>
> ```
> >>>
> >>> del a
> ```
>
> Referencing the name `a` hereafter is an error (at least until another
>   value is assigned to it). We'll find other uses for `del` later.

So only `del a` actually deletes `a`, `a = []` rebinds a to a new object and  `del a[:]` clears  `a`. In your second test if `b` did not hold a reference to the object it would be garbage collected.

Answer (score 5):

```
del a
```

is removing the variable `a` from the scope. Quoting from [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-del-statement):

> Deletion of a name removes the binding of that name from the local or
>   global namespace, depending on whether the name occurs in a global
>   statement in the same code block.

```
del a[:]
```

is simply removing the contents of `a`, since the deletion is passed to the `a` object, instead of applied to it. Again from the docs:

> Deletion of attribute references, subscriptions and slicings is passed
>   to the primary object involved; deletion of a slicing is in general
>   equivalent to assignment of an empty slice of the right type (but even
>   this is determined by the sliced object).

.

Answer (score 3):

Of those three methods, only the third method actually results in deleting the list that 'a' points to. Lets do a quick overview.

When you right `a = [1, 2, 3]` it creates a list in memory, with the items [1, 2, 3] and then gets 'a' to point to it. When you write `b = a` this preforms whats' called a 'shallow copy,' i.e. it makes 'b' point to the same block of memory as 'a.' a deep copy would involve copying the contents of the list into a new block of memory, then pointing to that.

now, when you write `a = []` you are creating a new list with no items in it, and getting 'a' to point to it. the original list still exists, and 'b' is pointing to it.

in the second case, `del a` deletes the pointer to [1,2,3] and not the array it's self. this means `b` can still point to it.

lastly, `del a[:]` goes through the data 'a' is pointing to and empties it's contents. 'a' still exists, so you can use it. 'b' also exists, but it points to the same empty list 'a' does, which is why it gives the same output.

Comment: The third method doesn't *delete* the list, it clears its contents.

Comment: whoops. yep. there's still an empty list

Answer (score 0):

To understand the difference between different ways of deleting lists, let us see each of them one by one with the help of images.

```
>>> a1 = [1,2,3]
```

A new list object is created and assigned to `a1`.

[image: i1]

```
>>> a2 = a1
```

We assign `a1` to `a2`. So, list `a2` now points to the list object to which `a1` points to.

[image: i2]

**DIFFERENT METHODS EXPLAINED BELOW:**

**Method-1   Using `[]` :**

```
>>> a1 = []
```

[image: i3]

On assigning an empty list to `a1`, there is no effect on `a2`. `a2` still refers to the same list object but `a1` now refers to an empty list.

**Method-2  Using `del [:]`**

```
>>> del a1[:]
```

[image: i4]

This deletes all the contents of the list object which `a1` was pointing to. `a1` now points to an empty list. Since `a2` was also referring to the same list object, it also becomes an empty list.

**Method-3 Using `del a1`**

```
>>> del a1
>>> a1
NameError: name 'a1' is not defined
```

[image: i5]

This deletes the variable `a1` from the scope. Here, just the variable `a1` is removed, the original list is still present in the memory. `a2` still points to that original list which `a1` used to point to. If we now try to access `a1`, we will get a `NameError`.