# Python: "Chained definition" of ints vs lists

Tags: python

I just discovered in the definition of variables in Python. Namely:

```
a = b = 0
a = 1
```

gives me `a=1` and `b=0` or a and b are two independent variables.

But:

```
a = b = []
a.append(0)
```

gives me `a = [0]` and `b = [0]`, or a and b are two references to the same object. This is confusing to me, how are these two cases different? Is it because `int` are primitive types or because lists are just pointers?

Comment: the 2 operation are different. In first case you assign a new value to a, while on second modify the object pointed by a...

Comment: The tests are not consistent. Try `a = b = []; a = [1, 2, 3]`

Comment: Relevant video: [Facts and Myths about Python names and values](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AEJHKGk9ns)

Comment: Downvoters: this is a perfectly reasonable question, and something that trips a lot of Python programmers up.

Comment: And in text form: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: See a popular answer of mine [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29810632/different-ways-of-deleting-lists/29810816#29810816).

Comment: Also try `a=b=[];a+=[1];a;b;a=a+[2];a;b`. The difference is that `a+=` mutates the original object, `a=a+` creates a new object and binds that to the name `a`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`a` and `b` point to the *same object always*. But you cannot alter the integer, it is immutable.

In your first example, you *rebound* `a` to point to another object. You did not do that in the other example, you never assigned another object to `a`.

Instead, you asked the object `a` *references* to alter itself, to add another entry to that object. All other references to that same object (the `list`), will see these changes. That's because `list` objects are mutable.

A proper comparison would be to re-assign `a` to point to a new list object:

```
a = b = []
a = [0]
```

Now you rebound `a` and `b` is still referencing the first list object.

Answer (score 1):

You must understand that `a` and `b` are simply references that point to an initially empty list:

```
>>> a = [] # set variable a to an empty list
>>> b = a  # sets b to what a is pointing to
>>> a.append(0) # add a zero to the original

# Step 1: A --> [ ]
# Step 2: A --> [ ] <-- B
# Step 3: A --> [0] <-- B
```