# Difference between assigning any value to a[ ] and a[ : ]

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I am a beginner in image processing i am learning it using OpenCV library.
While working with it i came across the following code snippet

```
import numpy as np  
img = np.zeros((300, 512, 3), np.uint8)    
img[:] = [b, g, r]
```

When i do `img=[b,g,r]`

It does not work as expected. I understand that this is may be because of the dimension of the array as initialized with `numpy` but i am not able to visualize it. Can anyone explain how this syntax work ?

Comment: From where the `b`/`g`/`r` came from? Did you receive an error message, if so can you add it?

Comment: I think you will find the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29810632/different-ways-of-deleting-lists

Comment: Without knowing what you did expect, I'm not sure how I can answer your question. Please provide an MCVE.

Answer (score 3):

`img[:]` will do in-place reassignment. It'll essentially reassign `img` to a whole **new** list, but in the **same place** in memory.

If you do `img = [b,g,r]`, your variable `img` will still point to an array `[b,g,r]`, however, it is pointing to a completely new location now. The idea is that if you have `img` already, there's no need to allocate new space for `[b,g,r]`.

Comment: sorry i made a mistake i meant img=[b,g,r]

Answer (score 2):

Let's simplify your example a bit, and define the 3 unknowns:

```
In [140]: b, g, r = 1,2,3                                                       
In [141]: x = np.zeros((4,2,3),int)
```

The `img=[b,g,r]` just assigns the list to the variable `img`.  The fact that you already had assigned a value to that variable doesn't make a difference.  In Python we don't "initialize" variables (as is sometimes done in other languages).

```
In [142]: [b,g,r]                                                               
Out[142]: [1, 2, 3]
```

Assigning that list to `x[:]` results in:

```
In [143]: x[:] = [b,g,r]                                                        
In [144]: x                                                                     
Out[144]: 
array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3]],

       [[1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3]],

       [[1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3]],

       [[1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3]]])
```

Effectively the list is converted to a (3,) array, `np.array([b,g,r])`.  Those values are assigned, with broadcasting thus:

```
(3,) => (1,1,3) => (4,2,3)
```

And by the broadcasting rules, this would only work if `b,g,r` were scalars.