# Cannot clear a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, reset

An object has a list of dictionaries:

```
self.aggregator = []
self.aggregator.append({'type': 'Log', 'entry': logline1})
self.aggregator.append({'type': 'Log', 'entry': logline2})
print self.aggregator
```

Everything is OK so far as seen:

```
[{'type': 'Log', 'entry': 'Content of logline 1'}, {'type': 'Log', 'entry': 'Content of logline 2'}]
```

Then I try to reset the contents of this list using different approaches:

```
self.aggregator = []
del self.aggregator
```

Now when I print the list it is empty:

```
[]
```

But when I check the length of the list, it still has its old size:

```
>> print len(self.aggregator)
2
```

Why is this possible, did I miss anything?

=== Update

Complete demo code below. I figured out what causes the error. It's the line with "del self.aggregator". When I delete this line, everything works as expected. Tested this behaviour on OS X with Python 2.7.10 and Python 2.7.11 (32bit) on Windows 7.

```
class Checker(object):

    aggregator = []
    aggregator_max = 10

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def finalizeAggregator(self):
        string = "\n".join([attribute['string'] for attribute in self.aggregator])

        # Check for a match on all the aggregator content
        match_result = self.checkString(string,"")

        if match_result:
            # If match has been found, check the aggregator contents one by one
            for element in self.aggregator:
                self.checkString(element["string"],
                                 element["module"],
                                 use_aggregator=False)

        # Clear aggregator
        print self.aggregator
        self.aggregator = None
        self.aggregator = []
        del self.aggregator
        print self.aggregator
        print len(self.aggregator)

    def checkString(self, string, module, use_aggregator=False):

            # If aggregator should be used
            if use_aggregator:
                print "USING aggregator"

                # As long as the aggregator is not full
                if len(self.aggregator) <= self.aggregator_max:

                    #if string not in self.aggregator:
                    # Add element to aggregator
                    self.aggregator.append({"string": string,
                                            "module": module})

                # Process aggregator if full
                if len(self.aggregator) >= self.aggregator_max:
                    self.finalizeAggregator()

                # Otherwise return
                else:
                    return False

            else:
                print "NOT using aggregator"

            if "evil" in string:
                print "WARNING!!!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    checker = Checker()
    checker.checkString('This is benign', 'test', use_aggregator=True)
    checker.checkString('This is benign', 'test', use_aggregator=True)
    checker.checkString('This is benign', 'test', use_aggregator=True)
    checker.checkString('This is benign', 'test', use_aggregator=True)
    checker.checkString('This is benign', 'test', use_aggregator=True)
    checker.checkString('This is benign', 'test', use_aggregator=True)
    checker.checkString('This is benign', 'test', use_aggregator=True)
    checker.checkString('This is benign', 'test', use_aggregator=True)
    checker.checkString('This is benign', 'test', use_aggregator=True)
    checker.checkString('This is benign', 'test', use_aggregator=True)
    checker.checkString('This is benign', 'test', use_aggregator=True)
    checker.checkString('This is benign', 'test', use_aggregator=True)
    checker.checkString('This is benign', 'test', use_aggregator=True)
    checker.checkString('This is benign', 'test', use_aggregator=True)
    checker.checkString('This is benign', 'test', use_aggregator=True)
    checker.checkString('This is benign', 'test', use_aggregator=True)
    checker.checkString('This is evil', 'test', use_aggregator=True)
    checker.checkString('This is benign', 'test', use_aggregator=True)
    checker.checkString('This is benign', 'test', use_aggregator=True)
    checker.checkString('This is benign', 'test', use_aggregator=True)
    checker.checkString('This is benign', 'test', use_aggregator=True)
    checker.checkString('This is benign', 'test', use_aggregator=True)
    checker.checkString('This is benign', 'test', use_aggregator=True)
    checker.checkString('This is benign', 'test', use_aggregator=True)
    checker.checkString('This is benign', 'test', use_aggregator=True)
    checker.checkString('This is benign', 'test', use_aggregator=True)
    checker.checkString('This is benign', 'test', use_aggregator=True)
    checker.checkString('This is benign', 'test', use_aggregator=True)
```

Comment: Could you post a minimal, verifyable example? I tried to verify the described behaviour with a little test-class but I cannot reproduce your issue. Please post more code.

Comment: I can't reproduce this... It works for me and furthermore after del it throws a NameError exception of object undefined.

Comment: Please post your code. You should not be able to use self.aggregator when you delete it using del keyword.

Comment: I think you are missing something. It works perfectly.

Comment: This line `del self.aggregator` should delete the variable, so when you ask for its value you should get an error. More code please.

Comment: Posted a code sample

Comment: @JohnGalt: The `del` is not the real error, it just reveals the real error. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34902561/364696).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined `aggregator` as a class attribute; until you assign to `self.attribute` directly, it's a *shared* class attribute. But when you do:

```
self.aggregator = None
```

that auto-vivifies an *instance* attribute. So after that point, it's a completely different variable that shadows (hides) the class attribute. Except when you do `del self.aggregator`, you delete the instance attribute, and unshadow the class attribute, seeing the original (shared) value.

If the goal is to have an instance attribute, use an instance attribute. Change:

```
class Checker(object):

    aggregator = []
    aggregator_max = 10

    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

to:

```
class Checker(object):
    aggregator_max = 10

    def __init__(self):
        self.aggregator = []
```

and it will be solely an instance variable (just don't `del` the actual attribute if you intend to use it later, that's nonsensical; assigning the empty `list` is fine though).

Note that there is a difference between assigning the empty `list` (replacing the *reference* held in `self.aggregator`) and deleting the *contents* of the `list` referenced by `self.aggregator` (`del self.aggregator[:]` or in Py3.3+, `self.aggregator.clear()`) in the case where there might be more than one reference to the `list` referenced by `self.aggregator`. Take a look at [Clearing Python lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/850795/364696) for more details.