# Empy a dictionary and a list in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I know that a list/dictionary can be emptied by re-initializing new objects, but I want to keep the initial objects.

1. Also in Python 3 a list can be empty(removed) all elements, by using `clear()`. But how can be done in Python 2.7 ?
2. Remove all keys from a dictionary ?

Comment: Have you tried using `dict.clear`?

Comment: For lists, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850795/different-ways-of-clearing-lists

Comment: [`dict.clear`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.clear) exists in [tag:python-2.7]…

Comment: @deceze but not `list.clear`, that is what they meant

Comment: For List try  del command 

    del list[:]

Comment: @Chris Sure, there's a dupe for that…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for a list:

```
l[:] = []
```

keeps the same object but empties the contents