# Create an empty list

Tags: python-3.x, list

I wanted to create an empty list and so I wrote the following code mentioned below. But the output it gave me was totally different. I am unable to make a conclusion as to why it came out like that:
my python code is as follows:

my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6]

for i in my_list:
my_list.remove(i)

print(my_list)

Output:
[2,4,6]

I tried writing a for loop and use .remove() function thinking that i will remove each element in the iteration.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850795/different-ways-of-clearing-lists) shows how to do it.

Comment: [Why your solution does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list-while-iterating-over-it-in-python).

Answer (score 0):

first you can always define empty list as `my_list = []`. And here as you are updating your list on every iteration. So, your loop iteration will only be `3` as list size is getting reduced. So, it will keep other `3` items.